# CSS ~ How to align an elements right to another element(s)?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the vague title , i'm fairly new to CSS and I have a problem with aligning a scroll box exactly to the right of another element

my page looks like this now:

[image]

I want it to look like this (i did some editing):

[image]

here is my html code and css styling of the boxes:

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
  }

  li{
      color: lightgray;
      border: 1px solid;
      border-color: #8056c7;
      width: 60%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .box
  {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
  }

  #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;  }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 25px; margin-bottom: 13px; padding: 11px;}
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background:#444a57   ;   }

#msgbt,#bt
{
    background-color: #7850c0;
    border-color: #7850c0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {  
    width:5px;
    height:8px;
    
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {  
    background-color: rgba(53, 57, 71, 0.849);
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

#row1 {
    padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .button-container {
    display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
    justify-content: space-between; /* MDN: The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along the main axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the same. */
    align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
  }
  
  .button-left {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight: lighter;

  }
  
  .button-right {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  
  .button-centre {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }


  p{
    color: whitesmoke;
  }

  #border
  {
    background-color: #282c34; 
    border: 1px solid; 
    border-color: #6e4bac; 
    border-radius: 25px;
  }


  body {
    background-color: #252839;  
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    }
    .container {max-width: 500px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
    .center { margin: 0 auto;}
    .terminal {
     animation: blink 1s infinite step-end;
    }
    
    @keyframes blink {
      from, to { opacity: 0; }
      
      50% {opacity: 1;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color: #21252b;">
        <h1 style="color: lightgrey; text-align: center;">placeholder</h1>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="jumbotron" id="border" >

                <div id="messages" style="height:auto;width:auto;border:1px solid #6e4bac; max-height: 640px; overflow:auto; border-radius: 25px; padding: 15px; background-color: #282c3469; scroll-behavior: smooth;">
                    <div id="spot" >   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="messages" style="height:auto;width:auto;border:1px solid #6e4bac; overflow:auto; border-radius: 25px; padding: 15px; background-color: #282c3469; float: right;">
            <h1 style="color: white;">placeholder</h1>
            <p>placeholder</p>
            <p>placeholder</p>
            <p>placeholder</p>
            <p>placeholder</p>
        </div>
```

EDIT: added CSS file some styles in the css files aren't related to this example page , I just made this example page out from bigger page for clarifying purposes

Comment: Why do you have inline styling if you have classes already defined?

Comment: I've made an edit. Make sure to note that you need to remove the `padding` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added `display: inline-block;` / removed `padding: 10px;` to your `.center` css to achieve the desired result.

```css
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  li{
      color: lightgray;
      border: 1px solid;
      border-color: #8056c7;
      width: 60%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .box
  {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
  }

  #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;  }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 25px; margin-bottom: 13px; padding: 11px;}
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background:#444a57   ;   }

#msgbt,#bt
{
    background-color: #7850c0;
    border-color: #7850c0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {  
    width:5px;
    height:8px;
    
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {  
    background-color: rgba(53, 57, 71, 0.849);
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

#row1 {
    padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .button-container {
    display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
    justify-content: space-between; /* MDN: The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along the main axis. The spacing between each pair of adjacent items is the same. */
    align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
  }
  
  .button-left {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight: lighter;

  }
  
  .button-right {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  
  .button-centre {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }


  p{
    color: whitesmoke;
  }

  #border
  {
    background-color: #282c34; 
    border: 1px solid; 
    border-color: #6e4bac; 
    border-radius: 25px;
  }


  body {
    background-color: #252839;  
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    }
    .container {max-width: 500px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;}
    .center { margin: 0 auto;}
    .terminal {
     animation: blink 1s infinite step-end;
    }
    
    @keyframes blink {
      from, to { opacity: 0; }
      
      50% {opacity: 1;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color: #21252b;">
        <h1 style="color: lightgrey; text-align: center;">placeholder</h1>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="jumbotron" id="border" >

                <div id="messages" style="height:auto;width:auto;border:1px solid #6e4bac; max-height: 640px; overflow:auto; border-radius: 25px; padding: 15px; background-color: #282c3469; scroll-behavior: smooth;">
                    <div id="spot" >   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="messages" style="height:auto;width:auto;border:1px solid #6e4bac; overflow:auto; border-radius: 25px; padding: 15px; background-color: #282c3469; float: right;">
            <h1 style="color: white;">placeholder</h1>
            <p>placeholder</p>
            <p>placeholder</p>
            <p>placeholder</p>
            <p>placeholder</p>
        </div>
```